# Merge more fonts elements into one

Tags: php, html, fonts

so I have this piece of html:

```html
<FONT COLOR="#c0504d"><FONT FACE="Verdana, sans-serif"><FONT SIZE=6 STYLE="font-size: 22pt">John
Smith</FONT></FONT></FONT>
```

I was wondering if I could merge all 3 fonts into one so the result looks like this:

```html
<FONT SIZE=6 STYLE="font-size: 22pt" FACE="Verdana, sans-serif" COLOR="#c0504d">John
Smith</FONT>
```

I intend to do it with php, but any other solutions are welcomed

Comment: I know, but it's a part from the project

Comment: Is your question if that format is valid? Or is you question how to convert the 1st code block to the 2nd code block using php?

Comment: how to convert the 1st one to the second

Answer (score 2):

The `font` tag has been deprecated for a while. You should use a non deprecated element and style it with CSS. Here's an example using a `span`.

```
<span style="font-size: 22pt; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; color:#c0504d;">John Smith</span>
```

You can see the mark up renders the same (or almost the same, I didn't test in multiple browsers) here, https://jsfiddle.net/39L1djer/1/.

Comment: yes, but i need to merge them using php, and later to transform it in xml

Comment: Can you clarify the question? There's no PHP in your question, nor XML.